# How to read a specific key-value pair from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a mongodb collection `users` like this:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" :"Backus"
  },
}
```

How do I retrieve `name.first` from this without providing `_id` or any other reference. Also, is it possible that pulling just the `name^ can give me the array of embedded keys (first and last in this case)? How can that be done?

`db.users.find({"name.first"})` didn't work for me, I got a:

> SyntaxError "missing: after property id (shell):1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The first argument to `find()` is the query criteria whereas the second argument to the `find()` method is a projection, and it takes the form of a document with a list of fields for inclusion or exclusion from the result set. You can either specify the fields to include (e.g. `{ field: 1 }`) or specify the fields to exclude (e.g. `{ field: 0 }`). The `_id` field is implicitly included, unless explicitly excluded.

In your case, db.users.find({name.first}) will give an error as it is expected to be a search criteria.

To get the name json :
    `db.users.find({},{name:1`})

If you want to fetch only name.first

```
db.users.find({},{"name.first":1})
```

Mongodb Documentation link [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/)

Comment: While using it in mongo shell at least, I need to put quotes around "name.first" in case I need to fetch only name.first

Answer (score 1):

In 2022

```
const cursor = db
  .collection('inventory')
  .find({
    status: 'A'
  })
  .project({ item: 1, status: 1 });
```

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all the record details:
 db.users.find({"name.first":""})
To fetch just the name or specific field:
db.users.find({{},"name.X":""}); 
where X can be first, last .

dot(.) notation can be used if required to traverse inside the array for key value pair  as
db.users.find({"name.first._id":"xyz"});