# generate a specific key pair from mongodb from UNIX shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using mongodb and am trying to get a specific value from a collection in the db. I am able to get the complete export using

```
mongoexport --db database --collection name
```

But the output is a large file and I am trying to get a specific set of key/pair in it.

```
ex: "Name": "Value"
```

there are several names and I just need to print all the names in the collection.

What would be the command syntax from a UNIX shell ?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927295/how-to-read-a-specific-key-value-pair-from-mongodb-collection) but that is from with in the mongo shell.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To request all fields from collection `yourCollection` in  `MyDatabase` :

```
mongo --quiet 127.0.0.1/MyDatabase --eval 'printjson(db.yourCollection.find().toArray());'
```

To request only fields `name` field from collection `yourCollection` in  `MyDatabase` :

```
mongo --quiet 127.0.0.1/MyDatabase --eval 'printjson(db.yourCollection.find({},{"_id":0,"name":1}).toArray());'
```

Comment: thanks - exactly what I needed - and very easy to format from here on.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a script to execute and save you the time of manually writing in those commands. Execute something like

```
mongo localhost:27017/test myfile.js
```

and in the javascript file input

```
db.name.findOne()
db.name().find({},{"_id":0,"Name":1}).toArray());
```

please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/     and [[How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts][2])

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to export documents matching a specific condition from the database, you can pass a query to `mongoexport` using the `-q` parameter. For example:

```
mongoexport -d db -c coll -q '{"Name":"Value"}'
```

This will export all documents containing the field "Name" having the value "Value".

You can also pass the `--quiet` parameter to `mongoexport` if you prefer to have the output without any informative content, such as number of exported documents.

Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ for more information regarding the `mongoexport` tool.