# How to read a specific key-value pair from mongorepository

Tags: mongodb, java-8, mongorepository

I am storing as an nested objects inside mongodb.
My data looks like below:

```
"test":{
    "serviceNAme01": {
              "name-01": "value",
              "name-02": "value2"
            },
    "serviceName02": {
              "name-01": "value",
              "name-02": "value2"
            },
       }
```

Using query like
`Query("{}, {'test.serviceNAme01': ''}")` gives nested exception - `org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Query { "$java" : Query: {}, Fields: {}, Sort: {} } returned non unique result.] with root cause.`

Note - this query returns the expected result in mongo console.

Even using `@Query(" {'test.serviceNAme01': ''}")` gives empty {}.

How to write query to get specified results inside nested object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927295/how-to-read-a-specific-key-value-pair-from-mongodb-collection

Comment: I tried out this....In mongo console it works but when I need to implement via sprin-boot mongorepository this query didnt work.